# MySQL Simple Query Optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  b.item_name,
  COUNT(distinct c.user_id) AS total_count,
  AVG(c.item_rating) AS avg_rating
FROM       item_ratings as c
INNER JOIN items AS b ON b.item_id = c.item_id
INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id = c.user_id
WHERE item_active = 1 AND u.user_valid = 1
GROUP BY c.item_id
```

This query runs for 500 seconds on a highly optimized database - not sure what is going on.

**Indexs**

```
item_ratings - item_user_id, (item_id, user_id), item_rating, item_id
users - user_id, user_valid
items - item_id (primary), item_search (item_id, item_name), item_r (parent_id, item_id, item_active)
```

**Table Size**

The item_ratings table close to 5 million records, while the items table is around 200k and users is around 250k.

**Explain**

The explain query seems to do a table sort on items (returning all 200k rows), even though there is a index on item_active. The other tables (item_ratings and user) both use the correct index.

**UPDATES**

**FULL EXPLAIN**

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref       rows  Extra
1   SIMPLE  b   ALL     PRIMARY,item_id, item_search, item_r    NULL    NULL    NULL    218419  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  c   ref     item_user_id ,user_id, item_id  4   myDB.b.item_id  29  Using where
1   SIMPLE  u   eq_ref  PRIMARY,user_valid,user_id  PRIMARY     4   myDB.c.user_id  1   Using where
```

**Hardware**
This is dedicated MySQL Server box running Ubuntu 10.10, whit 16GB of RAM. The tables are running MyISAM.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post the actual `EXPLAIN` output...

Comment: Explain output missing, show create table output missing, storage engine info missing, storage engine configuration variables missing, hardware you're using to run this - also missing info. No clue what kind of answer anyone can give with so much info not present.

Comment: I have done this now, sorry for the issue.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this query?  The reason it is running so long and not using the index is because it seems to be calculating these results for every item (200k+) in your table.  Simply put, the query is fetching this information on every item in your database.

Comment: @drew010 I need to get the ratings for every item in that is currently active. Once i do this, I insert each avg rating in to a temp folder for accessing throughout the day. I only run this query once and it used to be fine - but running for 500 seconds seems like a huge jump!

Comment: @gregavola Could you run and report how long these take? `SELECT item_id, COUNT(user_id) FROM item_ratings GROUP BY item_id` & `SELECT item_id, AVG(item_rating) FROM item_ratings GROUP BY item_id` ?

Comment: @njk Running the first one in Explain, I get no index and a table scan (it's a 5mm record table, so I assume this would be large). Same with the other query. No index is used.

Comment: @gregavola I think that's a starting point. Try using an index hint in your query. `USE INDEX (item_rating, item_id)`. Depending on how active your table is (CRUD), perhaps add another index (item_rating, item_id).

Comment: I read SELECT a.item_name, but 'a' is never defined? Am I missing something?

Comment: @njk It's pretty active, always doing updates and inserts depending if a user adds or updates a rating. I've tried using the USE INDEX on what you mentioned and it doesn't appear to be using it. It always dumps to a temp table and using file-sort (returning 5mm records)

Comment: @DirkMcQuickly yes - that's a mistake. Shuold be "b". Will update.

Comment: I would investigate on the "WHERE item_active = 1". The table "items" has an index where item_active is contained ("item_r (parent_id, item_id, item_active)"), but it cannot be used. "item_active" would have to be in the first place of a combined index or an index for itself.

Comment: This explains how combined indexes work and when they cannot be used: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys

Comment: @gregavola How many rows in `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item_ratings WHERE item_active = 1`? I would try to set up a view with this result set and trying the query with the view.

Comment: @njk item_active lives in the items table, not item_ratings. I'll try to add a straight index to item_active and see if that does the trick.

Comment: MySQL may not use an index if it has to examine a certain number of rows.  In this case, using the index is slower since it will end up reading the whole table anyway.  So what's changed when it used to run quickly vs taking 500 seconds?

Comment: @drew010 Nothign - I just think that the tables have grown since it first started. 5m records and 200k are lot of rows to parse through. I'm trying to cut it down by only doing only active users and active items. Would it be easier, to get a list of active items then grab the item count and avg rating for each item (so making smaller queries, on each row?)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.  This query should not be taking eight minutes.  One possibility is that the indexes are actually making the query worse, because the query wants to be a full table scan.  Before working around them, I suggest the following:

Presumably, the users and items table have a distinct id.  Also, presumably a user has only one rating for a given item.  If this is true, you can remove the count distinct and replace it with a count:

```
SELECT b.item_name, COUNT(c.user_id) AS total_count, AVG(c.item_rating) AS avg_rating
FROM item_ratings as c INNER JOIN
     items AS b
     ON b.item_id = c.item_id INNER JOIN
     users AS u
     ON u.user_id = c.user_id
WHERE item_active = 1 AND u.user_valid = 1
GROUP BY c.item_id
```

Second, there is not an index on "is_active".  The index is on (parent_id, item_id, item_active).  You query is not using parent_id, so this index will not be used.

Third, it appears to be going through the item index because of the aggregation.  Since you appear to want item_name instead of item_id, I would suggest changing the group by to:

```
group by c.item_name
```

This may allow it to generate a better query plan.

Answer (score 0):

Even with the index on the item_active field, the query still was EXTERMELY slow. Since this query only runs once per day, I found another solution that hopefully can be used for other users.

I basically just pulled a list of active beer only using this query:

```
SELECT b.beer_name
FROM items as b
WHERE b.item_active = 1
```

Then in each row, I looped through and got the the rating count and average rating for each active item like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.user_id) AS total_count, AVG(c.item_rating) AS avg_rating
FROM item_ratings as c 
INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id = c.user_id
WHERE item_active = 1 AND u.user_valid = 1 and b.item_id = @item_id
```

Where @item_id is the item_id from the PHP loop that I wrote. After this, I take the results of this and place it in to a table for querying. This solution works great for me because this small queries takes less than a second to run and can be run a batch style format during offpeak hours without causing any of the other tables to lock.

Thanks to everyone for the their suggestions and help!